# loop; passing two argument - 1:1 mapping

Tags: bash, shell, loops

If I have 50 different files to rename (or anything, basically two arguments). How would I do that with a for loop or any other method ?

```
mv $1 $2
```

I dont want to pass the argument with each instance. `$1 = ab` and `$2 = 1`.  50 differnt filenames.

Comment: Where do you have oldname, newname for each file? in a file?

Comment: I gave rename as an example. I wanted to know how 1:1 mapping can be done

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a list of txt files in current directory you want to rename:

```
for f in *.txt; do mv "$f" "renamed_$f"; done
```

I suggest adding `echo` after the do to see how the command would actually execute first, and then removing echo if it looks good.

For common file renaming tasks you might also want to consider using `mmv` which allows you to do pattern-based file renaming more easily.

Comment: Yup, adding quotes is advised, if names contain spaces or any funny chars interpreted by the shell. Thanks, Tom.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `filenames.txt` like this:

```
oldname1 newname1
oldname2 newname2
```

you can do like this:

```
xargs -L1 mv <filenames.txt
```

Comment: The documentation says: > The -l option is deprecated since the POSIX standard specifies -L instead.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I got the answer using arrays

```
OLD=(file text filename textfile)
NEW=(files1 text3 filename2 textfile3)
for i in {0..3}; do mv ${OLD[$i]} ${NEW[$i]};done
```